# Aggregate functions, Lack of Types, Entropy in Query problems on NoSQL DBs

Tags: sql, mongodb, couchdb, database, nosql

While we believe that NoSQL Databases have come to fill a number of gaps which are challenging on the side of RDBMS, i have had several challenges over time with NoSQL DBs in the area of their query eco-system. 
[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com) for example, like its mother [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) have had major improvements in reading data using views, lists, Key lookups, map reduce, e.t.c. Couchbase has even [moved to create](http://www.couchbase.com/press-releases/unql-query-language) an [SQL-like query engine](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql) for their huge 2.X verson. MongoDB has also made serious improvements and complex queries are possible on it and many other NoSQL DB developments going on out there.
Most [NoSQL DBs can perform Complex queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351040/431620) based on `LOGICAL and COMPARISON OPERATORS` e.g. `AND`, `OR`,`==` e.t.c However, aggergation and performing complex relations on data are a problem on my part. For example, in CouchDB and/or Couchbase, Views span only a single DB. It is not possible to write a view which will aggregate data from two or more databases.
 Let me now get to the problem. Functions (whether aggregate or not): `AVG`, `SUM`, `ROUND`,`TRUNC`,`MAX`, `MIN`, e.t.c The lack of data types makes it impossible to efficiently work with Date and Times hence the lack of Date and time functions e.g. `TO_DATE`,`SYSDATE` (for system date/time), `ADD_MONTHSs`, `DATE BETWEEN`, `DATE/TIME format Conversion` e.t.c. It is true, that many will say that , they lack Schemas, types and stuff, but, i have found myself not running away from the need for atleast any one of the functions listed up there. For example because NoSQL DBs have no Date/Time data type, it is hard to perform queries based on those, because you might want to analyse trends based on time. Also, others have tried to use UNIX/EPOC Time stamps and stuff to solve this but it aint a `single size fits all` solution.
 Map Reduce can be used to attain aggregation to a certain (small) degree, but the overhead has been realised to be great. However, the lack of `GROUP BY` functionality makes it a straineous solution to filter through what ou want. Look at the query below:

```
SELECT 
doc.field1, doc.field3, SUM(doc.field2 + doc.field4)
FROM 
couchdb.my_database 
GROUP BY doc.field1, doc.field3 
HAVING SUM(doc.field2 + doc.field4) > 20000;
```

This is not very easy to attain on CouchDB or Couchbase. i am not sure if its possible on MongoDB. I wish it were possible out of the box. This has made it difficult to use NoSQL as a Data warehouse or OLTP/OLAP solution. I found that, each time a complex analysis needs to be made, one needs to do it in the middle ware by paging through different datasets. Now, most experienced Guys (e.g. [`CLOUDANT`](https://cloudant.com/)) have tweaked [`LUCENE`](http://lucene.apache.org/) to perform complex queries, but because it was initially meant for indexing and text search, it has not solved the lack of `FUNCTIONS` and `DATA AGGREGATION` on most NoSQL DBs.
Because of lack of `FUNCTIONS`, most NoSQL DBs have the `NULL` data type but lack the option of converting `NULL` Objects to something else, like it is in some RDBMS. For example in Oracle, i could:  `NVL(COLUMN,0)` in order to include all the rows while performing say an `AVG` calculation on a given column (since say, by default the null columns will not be counted/included in the query processing). 
To fully understand the problem, CouchDB views for example operate within the scope of a doc like this below:

```
function(doc){
    // if statements, logical operators, comparison operators
    // e.t.c here. until you do am emit of that doc
    // if it satisfies the conditions set
    // emit(null, doc) OR emit(doc.x,[doc.y, doc.z]) e.t.c.
    // you can only emit javascript data types anyways
    emit(doc.field1,doc)
}
```

The docs which satisfy the filters, are let through and go onto the next stage or to a reduce function. Imagine a doc structure like this below:

```
{
    x: '',
    y: '',
    z: {
        p: '',
        n: N    // integer or number data type        
    },
    date: 'DD/MON/YYYY'  // date format
}
```

Now, lets imagine the possibility of this kind of query:

```
function(){
    var average = select AVG(doc.z.n) from couchdb.my_database;
    var Result = select doc.x,doc.y from couchdb.my_database where 
            doc.z.n > average and doc.y = 'some string' and 
            doc.date between '01-JUN-2012' and '03-AUG-2012';
    emit(Result);
}
```

OR if this query were possible:

```
function(){
    var latest = select MAX(doc.date) from couchdb.my_database;
    var Result  = select 
                    doc.x,doc.z.p,MONTHS_BETWEEN(doc.date,latest) as "Months_interval" 
                    from couchdb.my_database where doc.y like '%john%' 
                    order by doc.z.p;
    emit(Result);
}
```

**Qn 1:**  Which NoSQL Database solution has attained to a great degree, the query capability being talked about in the details above ? what key features make it stand out ? 
**Qn 2:**  Is the lack of a Schema, or the characteristic of being `Key-Value` a reason for the lack of `FUNCTIONS` in Querying these Databases ? What is the reason for the lack of Aggregate functionality in most NoSQL DBs ? 
**Qn 3:**  If the query ability above is possible in any of the NoSQL DBs, show how the last two (2) query problems above can be attained using the existing NoSQL infrastracture (consider any NoSQL technology of your choice)

Comment: You describe everything in SQL terms, what does SQL not give you that makes you want to consider noSQL?  It seems you are forcing the RDBMS paradigm onto nosql.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it should NOT be possible to run into the need for aggregation while working with NoSQL ? Haven't you ever had the need to get the `MIN` or `MAX` or `AVG` of some data in NoSQL ? I believe that such calculations are not tied to RDBMS by default. They are a need which arises from data processing, reporting, analysis e.t.c. That is what i think

Comment: Personally I work with couchbase, out of the box it offers count,sum,stats for map reduce jobs but the system is not an analytics system, nor is it brilliant for ad hoc queries but SQL is. With the sort of queries you want to do I would 100% use a RDBMS.

Comment: It is had to avoid relations, however small, from any database technology. For couchDB, because it lacks views that span two or more DBs at once, you are forced to save docs of diiferent structures in the same DB, which is okay, since the DB is schemaless. However, while organising user applications, separating different doc structures in different DBs is important, and hence forces you into a relational problem at a future time. I guess, this need is what forced Couchbase into implmeneting an SQL-like query engine. Think about it closely

Comment: In couchDB/Couchbase its easy to work with different document types


if(doc.docType =="DOC_TYPE) {
emit(data_here)
}


But still, from looking at your desired queries, use SQL.

Comment: Couchbase is a huge database. Clusterable, advanced distribution and replication. with that much data, how could one not run into a relational problem, or date range query problems. It is true that Arrays, timestamps e.t.c. if tinkered with, can help. However, this is not an inherent feature of the database engine. Due to Javascript support, it relieves much trouble, however, there are some problems which would not be fitted into the javascript domain especially data aggregation on top of a complex query. we could come up with some examples. Thanks for your input @avengesixfold

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  Yes obviously couchbase can work with data ranges, or searching on particular key ranges or keys.  However it is not a good fit for your more complex queries.  Thus I am telling you that SQL is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has something called Aggregation Framework and it works pretty well. I would say that almost every SQL Aggregation query could be carried out with this framework. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) you have some examples of "conversion" from SQL to Aggregation Framework.

Anyway MongoDB is a document oriented database and not key-value like CouchDB, so I don't know if it fits your requirements.

Comment: +1 Wow! Actually MongoDB has gone quite a long way into this. Thanks for the answer. However, CouchDB, Couchbase and Cloudant still lack these features.

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua Check out N1QL for couchbase in the future, still in development but more aligned with what you want. http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql